# Stored Proc in sql that does not return the value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

My function isn't returning anything - strReturn is empty:

```
        try
        {
            SqlParameter[] parameter = new SqlParameter[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@MerchantID", MercahntID),
                new SqlParameter("@LoactionID", LoactionID)
            };

            SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(DbConnString, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetMerchantLocationZip", parameter);

            return strReturn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError("Error Occurred When Retrieving Mercahnt Location Zip: MercahntID:" + MercahntID.ToString(), ex);
            return strReturn;
        }
    }
```

When I execute this stored proc using 'exec GetMerchantLocationZip (3333, 373773)' I get the correct zipcode in SQL. Why don't I get it in Visual Studio?

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMerchantLocationZip](
@MerchantID bigint,
@LoactionID bigint)

AS 

Begin

Select Zip FROM Merchant_Location 
where MerchantID=@MerchantID AND LocationID =@LoactionID

End
```

I am learning, so apologies if it's a obvious error. Thanks all!

Comment: Amazing Guys! Thanks all for all your help! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not getting results because you're not executing the code as a Query.

You're calling `SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery()` which doesn't return any results.

It looks like you're using the SqlHelper application block, so I think the code you want would be (if you're returning multiple rows in the query):

```
DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet(DbConnString,
                                      CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                                      "GetMerchantLocationZip",
                                      parameter);
```

`ds` will then contain the results of the query.

If you're trying to retrieve a single value from the database rather than a set of rows, then your code would be:

```
object zip = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(DbConnString,
                                     CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                                     "GetMerchantLocationZip",
                                     parameter);
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't appear to be assigning anything to `strReturn` anywhere. You would also need to use `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve the value from a single row, single column result set.

```
strReturn = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(...) as string;
```

Or an `OUTPUT` parameter with `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling ExecuteNonQuery which only returns the number of rows affected.  Try this:

```
var zipCode = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(DbConnString, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetMerchantLocationZip", parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check your spelling!!** You're probably throwing an exception in the SQL statement because you've misspelled "Merchant" or "Location" somewhere (or many places).

And, as others have pointed out, you probably want this:

```
return SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(DbConnString, 
    System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
    "GetMerchantLocationZip", parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ExecuteNonQuery which doesn't return results, it's just going to return the number of rows updated.  You want to execute a reader.

Answer (score 0):

`strReturn` isn't being set, and you need to call `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to call the `ExecuteScalar` instead of ExecuteNonQuery as that is expected to have no return.

Perhaps the following code

```
 var zipObject = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(DbConnString, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetMerchantLocationZip", parameter);

 return (string)zipObject;
```